# Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on 00001910-00081XXXX19A201E. Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, xcode15, ios17

When im trying to run flutter project from **vsCode** onto my iPhone, suddenly this error started appearing :

> Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on 00001910-00081XXXX19A201E.
> Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
> open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Error launching application on iPhone.

**NOTE:** this started after i updated to **iOS 17** and **XCODE 15**.

Also, im able to run the app from XCODE and its working fine, only from **VsCode** & **Android Studio** its throwing this error

**Already tried the following:
**

1. Reseting iPhone 13
2. Reseting Macbook
3. flutter clean & flutter pub get
4. Revoking the signing ceritificate from XCODE
5. Unparing & paring the iPhone in XCODE.
6. Removed provisioning profile for the iPHone from the XCODE.
7. Uninstalling & reinsalling the app.
8. Also, there is no App developer certificate in Settings **>** General **>** VPN & Device Management, to accept or trust.

Comment: Running into this as well. What version of Flutter are you on?

Comment: same problem here, any tried all the provided solutions none work. Could be something related to latest iOS/Xcode?

Comment: related?: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/128531#issuecomment-1587984546

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by update the flutter version to the latest Flutter SDK 3.13.9
Dart SDK 3.1.5
then flutter clean & pub get
then pod install and pod update
then You may be prompted to give access to control Xcode. Flutter uses Xcode to run your app. If access is not allowed, you can change this through your Settings > Privacy & Security > Automation from your mac device

Note: the first run will run the Xcode only maybe Just go to the last step and disallow and allow it again from Settings > Privacy & Security > Automation from your mac device

if you try this solution it will work definitely.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **Solution 1:**

**Open Settings > Developer**

**Click on Clear trusted computer**

**Then click on trust this computer**

**Run `flutter clean` `flutter pub get`**

> **Solution 2:**

**1-** Force close your Xcode

**2-** Run your app again

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved by updating the flutter version, like the image
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i'll definitely try this.